# How to pass variable with an apache RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to pass for example:

```
www.example.com/quote/20.html
```

to:

```
www.example.com/quote.php?id=20
```

mod_rewite is on and the current rules do not seem to pass the variable:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
# STRONG HTACCESS PROTECTION
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
 satisfy all
</Files>


RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule quote/(.*).html quote.php?id=$1 

RewriteRule topic/(.*)/(.*).html topic.php?topic=$1&page=$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
# STRONG HTACCESS PROTECTION
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:htaccess)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /quote\.php\?id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^quote\.php$ /quote/%1? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^quote/(\d+).html$ /quote.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^topic/([^/]+)/(.+).html$ /topic.php?topic=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: When I change the upper part up until "RewriteEngine On" I get a 500 internal error. I changed all the rest but still no progress..

Comment: ".htaccess: Expected </FilesMatch> but saw </Files>"